# Editing a typo in question content

Tags: support, edits

I recently noticed lots of questions have a typo in their content such as 'WodPress' instead of 'WordPress'. However, when I attempt to edit the typo, an error message is displayed on screen:

> Edits must be at least 6 characters. Is there something else to
>   improve in this post?

What should I do if there is nothing else to improve? I'd still like amend the typo.

Comment: Those edits won't add much to the question. Leave them for the high-rep users to correct. Edits are meant to make the question more clearer and explain the problem much better. Minor typo edits won't hinder the question from being answered, so just let them be! :) Also you could just leave a comment to the OP and ask them to do it, and you can just clean up your comment later.

Comment: Those edits won't add much to the question - completely agree but you're missing a big issue - SEARCH. Will searching for WordPress find a question that has only 'wodpress' in it? That's a very basic example but hopefully you can see my point about typos being important.

Comment: That's where the tags come into picture. If the question is related to *WordPress*, then the OP would have tagged the question appropriately and that is enough to bring the question in the search results. I hope you see why typos aren't that big a deal(atleast in most cases). There can be very rare cases where it can be a possibility but then, there are so many high-rep users around that one of them is surely to find it and fix it! :)

Comment: Agreed about tags! They're a great way to find questions - I use them lots. But on your point: "there are so many high-rep users around that one of them is surely to find it and fix it" - there are 10,000 if not 100,000 of typos across the site - some date back years so this isn't guaranteed :)

Comment: My point is, even they don't get addressed, they still show up in the search results. Typos aren't that big a problem, IMHO. The fact that you could locate few questions dating years back having silly typos mean that they are easily searchable and typos fix isn't the priority now. Sure, I agree they need to be fixed, but it is a long process and the community is working on it. I'd love to see you get the 2k privileges and start up with nice clean up jobs. But beware, too many such small edits might bump questions which weren't active for a long time to the active questions and that ain't good.

Comment: I think bumping of questions after a typo amendment should be stopped if possible - that doesn't benefit anybody. Regarding me locating a few questions dating back years - I could only do that because I was specifically searching for the typo. That particular question (with the typo) would still be in the question graveyard (unless somebody searched for 'wodpress')

Comment: If you feel so much about this, I suggest you post a feature-request on MSO regarding the bumping of questions on minor typo edits and have the community and the SE team decide upon it. IMO, this is a valid feature and would be pretty helpful. But will it out-weigh the dis-advantages it'd gonna with itself needs to be looked into. You can think about it and come up with a detailed feature-request and post it here on MSO :)

Comment: @henrywright Link to the post in question?

Comment: Hi Bart - I could actually link to *many* - just doing a quick search I can see this one is a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147602/shortcodes-ultimate-plugin-modification-with-extra-divs

Comment: @ail-e - you're right, this question is a duplicate. My apologies

Comment: I thought you had a specific instance in mind @henrywright. But my point [is still illustrated by this one](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15147602/revisions). 23 characters right there. In most (if not all) cases brought up here as problematic due to the character limit, there is more than enough to fix to get over it. Don't just focus on a single issue. Check the whole post. You should rarely have the problem then.

Comment: [Anyway, I've edited/voted/closed/flagged all those question and answers.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wodpress)

Comment: +1 to Bart's comment - agreed you can always look for more to edit. But editing should be avoided for the sake of editing. There should actually be something worthy of editing before an edit is made

Comment: @rene great! Now for 'Wordpres', 'Facebok', 'Tumbler'... hehe just kidding :)

Answer (score 5):

If there is nothing else to fix (which is absolutely rare) then leave the edit to users having enough rep to do it without going through the review system.

Comment: The OP could also edit? leaving a comment could als be an option in that case?

Comment: @rene **yes**, that's a good way too. Maybe it's not strictly needed, but I would prefer to know I made a typo I should fix. I would flag your comment as obsolete immediately, of course.

Comment: If it is an obvious typo then someone will fix it. Otherwise it might not be so important. So IMO a comment is not necessary.

Comment: @rene, I've left more than a few custom "in the future comment giving the author your suggestions" reject reasons, unfortunately by the time I've typed that and hit reject it tells me "this edit has already been approved"

Comment: @OGHaza Hmmm, the robo-reviewers are becoming an issue it seems. I tend to suggest to hit reject as quickly as possible and leave the comment after the fact but that is more an emotional reaction than a sensible way...

Comment: juergen - you have 10,000s of typos across the site, some date back years. So, leaving the typos to users with higher rep isn't a great answer because they can't get them all. Not saying that I can get them all either :)

Comment: @henrywright: If a typo was not fixed in the first minutes after posting it, then nobody cared about it and will not care about in after years.

Comment: juergen-d I care :)

Comment: @henrywright, but when you submit a tiny edit like that 3-5 people have to waste their time reviewing it, and the question bumps up to the front page despite no new interest in it.

Comment: @henrywright: And besides we have **30000** users that can edit posts without going through the review system.

Comment: OGHaza - that isn't an excuse for leaving typos on the site. The procedure *could* be amended and the bumping of questions *could* be stopped (only for typo amendments). I'm not saying the procedure should change - I'm saying how can typos in questions be tackled better!

Comment: @henrywright. I *enjoy* editing, and do a lot of fixing small typos. I also do a lot of completely rewriting posts to make them comprehensible. But there are only so many hours in the day.

Comment: @trig-is-timothy-richard-green yes completely agreed